# MFC Object serialization in C#

Tags: c#, c++, serialization, binaryfiles, carchive

I am trying to read a binary file in C# which has been written actually using CArchive. I have done most of the part but stuck in reading an object. Instead of writing bool, int, double object has been written into binary.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bfsbt0t(v=vs.110).aspx
```

So original code is something like this.

```
MyClass myObject;
if (archive.IsStoring()
    archive << myObject;
else
    archive >> myOjbect;
```

So question is how can I translate this piece of code in C#.

```
void Read(BinaryReader reader)
{
    // Read MyClass object here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a comparable C# object (you might want to use C++/CLI) and construct it from the file.

It would help if you specified what `myObject` is.

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: I have tried some more debugging, when writing object Serialize method is called and it writes int, doubles in it. But when reading it doesn't read that in order. I skipped some bytes and then tried to read, and it worked. Looks like archive >> myObject writes something extra (Class name I guess).

Comment: Hi @fhnaseer , I am also  converting a  MFC Serialization to C# .  How did you figure out how the data was saved , and read via CArchive.